# DrillDownLevel causing rows to be duplicates

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap-cube

I have defined a cube with a hieararchy of Dates such: Year is a top level then there's Month level.

I have deployed the cube using SSAS VS 2022 and SQL Server 2019.

But when I query it using the following MDX expression:

```
WITH
MEMBER MEASURES.COUNT AS [Measures].[Count]                                                 
SELECT     MEASURES.COUNT    ON COLUMNS,
DRILLDOWNLEVEL({[TIME_DIM].[Hierarchy].[YEAR]} )   ON ROWS                                                                 
FROM [CUBE1]
```

I get results such as

```
Year    Month   Count
2020    1   20 #some rows such as this one are duplicates
2020    1   20 #some rows such as this one are duplicates
... ... ...
```

What could be the reason, did I miss defining a Level in a hieararchy in SSAS ?

Comment: Why are you defining a calculated measure for count? If its a base measure then I dont see the benefit.  Try removing the calculation and just use the base measure

Comment: its a customized count with the same name as the usual "count"